# invoke rserve from rclient timeout stuck

Tags: r

How do we invoke rserve from rsclient?  On server side we have a function which needs to be invokes from rsclinet. Any rseval call gets stuck - added "control-enable" flag but still does not work. Thanks

```
    Kindly find below sample code

    1. Server side - "rserve" 
    library(Rserve)
    Rserve(port=6311,args="--RS-enable-control --RS-enable-remote --RS-settings")

    2. Function present on server side as rscript - D:/axa/rsource/rsource/Functionaddition.R
   sumFunc=function()
   {
      print("function invoked")
      return(10)
    }


    3. Client (Rstudio) invoke function ("sumFunc")
       library("RSclient")
       c<- RSconnect(host = "localhost", port = 6311)
       source <-RSserverSource(c,"D:/axa/rsource/rsource/Functionaddition.R")
       RSserverEval(c,"z()")
```